# Is it guaranteed to be true that a subspace can be the empty set?

Tags: linear-algebra

Just like the title, but can a subspace be the empty vector set? Is it GUARANTEED to be true?

Comment: Depends on the context you're speaking of. If you mean vector spaces, no, no vector space is empty. The smallest vector space you can have is that consisting of only a zero vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. One of the axioms in the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) of a vector space postulates the existence of the zero vector.

Therefore, every vector space has at least one element.